# How to access the images/videos from another location (windows + disk E) in PHP?

Tags: php, .net, windows, smarty, symlink

We have one .net application in which there is facility to upload images in given storage location. our application is completely windows based. and what it does is it stores images on given path for example "E:\Images".

On the other hand We are using using PHP application (using smarty framework) to display all our uploaded data. In this case everything working fine except images as the storage location is not within the PHP application directory.

I know with the help of symbolic link we can access the images from another disk. It is also working. But if we change the storage location later on then there will be a problem.

I also know that using base64 way we can access images. But it is taking too much time to load If I have a 30 images for one single record.

Can you please suggest a good way how can I access the images? Or how we can improve our symbolic link way?

Answer (score 0):

PHP can access any area of the disk ifallowed. You may need to configure `open_basedir` to allow such access.